Synthesis of γ,δ unsaturated carboxylic acid via [3,3] sigmatropic rearrangement
I am planning on synthesising a γ,δ-unsaturated carboxylic acid. The reaction scheme is shown in the image below.
I have two questions regarding this reaction:
Question 1: What is the purpose of adding TMSCl (trimethylsilyl chloride)?
In the first step, LDA deprotonates one of the alpha hydrogens, resulting in a lithium enolate, which is then trapped by TMSCl. Is this to prevent the enolate from attacking the C=O group in the substrate (aldol reaction)? Clayden Organic Chemistry states that the unsaturated carboxylic acid product is the same, regardless of whether TMSCl is used or not. However, according to Clayden the reaction works better when TMSCl is used (Ref 1.) Why is that exactly?
Question 2: What is the purpose of adding methanol  after the reflux?
After the enolate is trapped by TMSCl and refluxed for 2 h, methanol is added. Is the methanol added to remove the TMS by first protonating the oxygen and then subsequent nucleophilic attack by methanol, yielding the carboxylic acid? Is methanol strong enough of an acid and nucleophile to do this (irreversibly)?
Reference:
Ref 1. Clayden, J., Greeves, N., Warren, S. Organic Chemistry (2nd edition, 2012). Chapter 35 Pericyclic reactions 2: sigma tropic and electrocyclic reactions (page 914).


According to this review, silyl groups are frequently used  to control the position of a double bond, with possibility of controlling the double-bond geometry.

Thank you for the useful comment! Clayden states that the product is the same when TMSCl is not used. What might the purpose of TMSCl be in this specific scenario?

Enolate is very unstable without trapping it. Silyl ester can be isolated and have more control. Thus, it may give a very high yield compared to non-trapped procedure.

The MeOH will remove the TMSi group to give the carboxylic acid plus MeOSiMe3

Does MeOH first protonate the oxygen attached to Si, and then MeOH attacks the Si atom?

@Jack  I think it is more likely to be direct nucleophilic attack by the oxygen on the silicon centre. This review may tell you  https://www.thieme-connect.com/products/ejournals/abstract/10.1055/a-2083-8591
